# asp.net mvc 2 and IIS 6 and json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I have an action: /bikes.json that returns some json (I have it as extension so that compression can be turned on).

While running on MS Visual Studio 2010 it works fine, the /bikes.json call my controller, it dynamically generates the json and returns it.

On IIS6 it does not work, and I get 404s.

How can I get it to work?

(I've tried experimenting with adding a new JSON MIME type, but that has not fixed the problem).

Any help very much appreciated.

Thanks

--MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS6, you need to map the .json extension to the ASP.NET ISAPI DLL. The problem is that your request isn't even getting to ASP.NET pipeline and ASP.NET MVC>

Comment: yes, except that the key is to unclick verify that the file exists.